# Issue authenticating to AD-joined Centos 7 server

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, centos7, sssd

Using [this link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/pdf/Windows_Integration_Guide/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-7-Windows_Integration_Guide-en-US.pdf), I have set up a server that is properly joined to an Active Directory server, but for some reason I can not authenticate to that server with a kerberos ticket on several test-users that I made on my laptop.

All users on my local laptop have the same .ssh/config and all use the same /etc/krb5.conf; all users are also able to succesfully get a valid ticket from the AD, just by using kinit. However, the problems arise when I try to ssh to the aforementioned server that is joined to AD.

When I try to login with my own account, 'parkel', it asks me for my password, I type in my AD-password and I get authenticated to login to the server, the first time I logged in, my homedir was made properly and I was assigned to the groups that were set in gidNumber in the AD; all seemed okay in the world. I tested changing gidNumber in AD, all changes were active right away after relogging. All still seemed okay in the world.

That's when the issues started; after seeing my success, I made two test-accounts in AD, copies of my own AD-account that was working before, 'test1' & 'test2'. I changed to that account on my laptop, did kinit and got a ticket. However, when I tried to login to the server, it's only trying to authenticate with password and no mention is ever made in the logs that it's trying to authenticate using pam_sss, since the local user does not exist, this will fail miserably.

I have checked out way more google searches and documentation than I care to admit, but I'm really at a loss here; I'm pretty sure I'm overlooking some stupid small detail, but I really can't find where I'm going wrong.

Included is some output from sshd log on the server and my krb5.conf on the server and on my client.

#### SSHD output

```
Dec 10 11:59:04 ldaptest.vs.lan sshd[2384]: Authorized to parkel, krb5 principal parkel@VS.LAN (ssh_gssapi_krb5_cmdok)
Dec 10 11:59:04 ldaptest.vs.lan sshd[2384]: Accepted gssapi-with-mic for parkel from 192.168.100.2 port 56752 ssh2
Dec 10 11:59:04 ldaptest.vs.lan systemd[1]: Created slice user-2001.slice.
Dec 10 11:59:04 ldaptest.vs.lan systemd[1]: Starting Session 3 of user parkel.
Dec 10 11:59:04 ldaptest.vs.lan systemd[1]: Started Session 3 of user parkel.
Dec 10 11:59:04 ldaptest.vs.lan systemd-logind[776]: New session 3 of user parkel.
Dec 10 11:59:04 ldaptest.vs.lan sshd[2384]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user parkel by (uid=0)
Dec 10 11:59:10 ldaptest.vs.lan sshd[2410]: Invalid user test1 from 192.168.100.2
Dec 10 11:59:10 ldaptest.vs.lan sshd[2410]: input_userauth_request: invalid user test1 [preauth]
```

#### KRB5.conf SERVER

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = VS.LAN 
    dns_lookup_realm = false
    dns_lookup_kdc = false
    ticket_lifetime = 24h
    renew_lifetime = 7d
    forwardable = yes

[realms]
    VS.LAN = {
        kdc = ad01-test.vs.lan:88
        admin_server = ad01-test.vs.lan:749
        default_domain = vs.lan
    }

[appdefaults]
    pam = {
        debug = true
        ticket_lifetime = 36h
        renew_lifetime = 36h
        forwardable = true
        krb4_convert = false
    }

[logging]
    default = FILE:/var/log/krb5/kdc.log
    kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5/kdc.log
    admin_server = FILE:/var/log/krb5/kadmind.log
```

#### KRB5.conf CLIENT

```
includedir /etc/krb5.conf.d/

[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = false
 rdns = false
 default_realm = VS.LAN 
 default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}

[realms]
 VS.LAN = {
  kdc = 172.19.254.5
 }

[domain_realm]
 .vs.local = VS.LAN
 vs.local = VS.LAN
```

#### SSSD.conf SERVER

```
[sssd]
domains = vs.lan
services = nss, pam, pac
config_file_version = 2

[nss]

[pam]

[pac]

[domain/vs.lan]
## Comment out if you want offline logins
# cache_credentials = true
ldap_id_mapping = False
default_shell = /bin/bash
fallback_homedir = /home/%d/%u

id_provider = ad
auth_provider = ad
access_provider = ad
chpass_provider = ad

ldap_schema = ad

dyndns_update = true
dyndns_refresh_interval = 43200
dyndns_update_ptr = true
dyndns_ttl = 3600

ad_server = ad01-test.vs.lan
```

Answer (score 1):

As a future reference, this log line is the key:

```
Dec 10 11:59:10 ldaptest.vs.lan sshd[2410]: Invalid user test1 from 192.168.100.2
```

It tells you that ssh can even find the user, so the next step in debugging should be to enable sssd logs and see why `getent passwd test1` is not working.

Glad sssd works for you now!

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solved my problem by settings the correct values uidNumber, gidNumber, homeDirectory and loginShell in AD for the user 'test1'; apparently when I copied my working user, these values were not copied along with all the rest of the information.